# Android: Xades URI error

Tags: java, android, xml-signature, xades4j

I am working on a xades-bes type signature with Android Studio. The library that I use is not xades4j. My country's government provided another library jor java and I am using it. I am trying to sign a XML file.

I have a XML file for my xades signature in */raw* directory (**not test file**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xmlsignature_config xmlns="http://uekae.tubitak.gov.tr/xml/signature#">
    <locale language="tr" country="TR"/>

    <http>
        <proxy-host></proxy-host>
        <proxy-port></proxy-port>
        <proxy-username></proxy-username>
        <proxy-password></proxy-password>
        <basic-authentication-username></basic-authentication-username>
        <basic-authentication-password></basic-authentication-password>
        <connection-timeout-in-milliseconds>2000</connection-timeout-in-milliseconds>
    </http>

    <!--
    IdResolver, DOMResolver, HttpResolver, XPointerResolver, FileResolver;
    -->
    <resolvers>
        <resolver class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.resolver.IdResolver"/>
        <resolver class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.resolver.DOMResolver"/>
        <resolver class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.resolver.HttpResolver"/>
        <resolver class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.resolver.XPointerResolver"/>
        <resolver class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.resolver.FileResolver"/>
    </resolvers>

    <timestamp-server>
        <host>http://tzd.kamusm.gov.tr</host>
        <digest-alg>SHA-256</digest-alg>
        <!-- leave below settings blank, if not ESYA Timestamp Server! -->
        <!-- for test timestamp account mail to bilgi@kamusm.gov.tr  -->
        <userid>user_id</userid>
        <password>password</password>
    </timestamp-server>

    <algorithms>
        <digest-method>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256</digest-method>
    </algorithms>

    <validation>

        <grace-period-in-seconds>0</grace-period-in-seconds>
        <!-- how old revocation data should be accepted? -->
        <last-revocation-period-in-seconds>17280000</last-revocation-period-in-seconds>
        <!-- compare resolved policy with the one at policy uri, if indicated -->
        <check-policy-uri>false</check-policy-uri>

        <!-- loosening below 2 settings will cause warnings instead of validation failure -->
        <!-- referenced validation data must be used for cert validation is set true -->
        <force-strict-reference-use>true</force-strict-reference-use>
        <!-- validation data must be published after creation ifs set true, requires grace period for signers -->
        <use-validation-data-published-after-creation>false</use-validation-data-published-after-creation>

        <validate-certificate-before-signing>false</validate-certificate-before-signing>

        <!-- if there is a signing time in the signature, decide if you want to trust -->
        <trust-signing-time>false</trust-signing-time>

        <validators>
            <!--
            valid profile types are XMLDSig, XAdES_BES, XAdES_EPES,  XAdES_T,
            XAdES_C, XAdES_X, XAdES_X_L and XAdES_A
            -->
            <profile type="XMLDSig">
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_BES" inherit-validators-from="XMLDSig">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.AllDataObjectsTimeStampValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.DataObjectFormatValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.IndividualDataObjectsTimeStampValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.SigningCertificateValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.SigningTimeValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.TurkishESigProfileAttributeValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.TurkishESigProfileValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_EPES" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_BES" >
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.SignaturePolicyValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_T" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_EPES">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.SignatureTimeStampValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_C" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_T">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.CompleteCertificateRefsValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.CompleteRevocationRefsValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.AttributeCertificateRefsValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.AttributeRevocationRefsValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_X" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_C">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.SigAndRefsTimestampValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.RefsOnlyTimestampValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_X_L" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_X">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.CertificateValuesValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.RevocationValuesValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.AttrAuthoritiesCertValuesValidator"/>
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.AttributeRevocationValuesValidator"/>
            </profile>
            <profile type="XAdES_A" inherit-validators-from="XAdES_X_L">
                <validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator.ArchiveTimestampValidator"/>
                <!--validator class="tr.gov.tubitak.uekae.esya.api.xmlsignature.validator."/-->
            </profile>
        </validators>
    </validation>

    <parameters>
        <!-- should referenced validation data be written to signature dir, or
        certvalidation is configured to write that data to somewhere
        eg local cert store? -->
        <write-referencedvalidationdata-to-file-on-upgrade value="false"/>

    </parameters>
</xmlsignature_config>
```

And in my mainActivity class related part of my code is:

```
 String sourceFilePath = filePathView.getText().toString();
                if (sourceFilePath.isEmpty()) {
                    exc = new Exception("No File Selected.");
                    return null;
                }
                mAPDUSmartCard.login(pwdText);
                Pair<CardTerminal, ECertificate> selection = certListAdapter.getSelection();
                ECertificate signCert = selection.second;
                BaseSigner signer = mAPDUSmartCard.getSigner(signCert.asX509Certificate(), Algorithms.SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);    

                Resources res1 = getResources();
                Config conf = new Config ( res1.openRawResource(R.raw.xmlsignature_config));
                Context context = new Context();
                context.setConfig(conf);

                XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(context);

                signature.addDocument( sourceFilePath, "application/xml", false);  // This part's first parameter can be the reason of error. 
                        signature.getSignedInfo().setSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA256);
                signature.addKeyInfo(signCert);
                signature.sign(signer);
                signature.write(new FileOutputStream(sourceFilePath + ".xsig"));
```

The program is working. However, when I choose the file and click the Sign button:

**1-** I am taking a reference error, in log it says that uri could not  found the path of **sourceFilePath** variable which is the path of file to sign.
It also gives a Reference id with the error.
When I give an empty string ("") instead of sourceFilePath variable, the program says the file has been signed ( I don't understand how can it be signed without giving parameter in  **addDocument** method. Anyway, the validation program for signed files does not validate the file because of reference not found error.

**2-** Also in my xml file **xmlns="http://uekae.tubitak.gov.tr/xml/signature#** line gives error of "Uri is not registered". I have done what I have found here but the problem was not solved. Can this situation be the reason for error that I face?

I have been working on this issue for days but still could not find any solution.